# Twitter like signup - don't do anything if input fields are left blank

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

Its simple but Im clueless in jquery. Basically I want to stop users from advancing onto the next page if there are blank inputs on the registration process, just like Twitter has.
This is what I came up with so far but its not working. I dont want to disable the button, I want it to be clickable but do nothing.

```
$('#registerform').submit(function(e) {
if (!$('#user_login, #user_email, #password, #repeat_password').val()) {
   e.preventDefault();
}       
});
```

This is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/melbourne/GgEZc/19/

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way -

```
$('#registerform').submit(function(e) {
    if ($('input.input').filter(function(){
          return this.value === "";
    }).length > 0) {
       e.preventDefault();
   }       
});
```

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/GgEZc/20/

Comment: Tried and same result as mine. Goes to the next page. Mine works too on fiddle but not on the actual page

Comment: @Klaus Do you mean form is submitted even if any input field is left blank?

Comment: Yes, submited loads the page and then throws the errors. and all input fields are empty of course.